# Querying existing linked tables from mySQL in a graphql resolver?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js, graphql-js

Currently, I'm connecting to database and creating tables with Sequelize, and doing the rest with Graphql, making the schemas, queries and resolvers.

I seem to have hit a wall with how to ask for the data from these 3 linked tables:

`CITY           CompLocations                   CompIssue
| id |         | locationID | compID |         | locationID | issueLevel |
|*1* | ----->  | 1          |  45    | ------> | 45         | *5*
| 2  |         | 2          |  203   |         | 203        | 3`

I just need to retrieve all the CompIssue.issueLevel's associated with CITY.id, via this existing relation/association.

Im looking at associations and querying in Sequelize's API. How would one query the above within a Grapql/Apollo resolver function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an older question but I hit on a similar issue recently. In my case I am using seriate to connect to an MSSQL server from Nodejs and wanted to create the GraphQL schema dynamically based on the DB design (following the linked fields and such to create the sub-queries). Going this route I got the sql:

```
`SELECT 
   BASE_TABLE = t.TABLE_NAME, 
   BASE_COLUMN = col.COLUMN_NAME, 
   DATA_TYPE, 
   LEN_PRECISION = COALESCE(
                             CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
                             numeric_precision, 
                             datetime_precision
                   ), 
   LINKED_TABLE = keys.Data_Table, 
   LINKED_COLUMN = keys.Data_Column 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t INNER JOIN 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col ON 
      t.TABLE_NAME = col.TABLE_NAME LEFT JOIN 
   ( SELECT 
            Base_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME, 
            Base_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME, 
            Data_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME, 
            Data_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME, 
            Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C INNER JOIN 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON 
               C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME INNER JOIN 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON 
               C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME INNER JOIN 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON 
               C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME INNER JOIN 
            ( SELECT 
                     i1.TABLE_NAME, 
                     i2.COLUMN_NAME 
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1 INNER JOIN 
                     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON 
                         i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
              WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
             ) PT ON 
             PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME 
   ) keys ON 
      keys.Base_Table = t.TABLE_NAME AND 
      keys.Base_Column = col.COLUMN_NAME 
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'`
```

This may not be the most elegant, and is likely to hit some performance issues on larger databases, but it worked well for me. The final dataset will give you the list of table/column pairs with any links to other table/column pairs from your database design.

From this dataset it should be "trivial" to check for the links and create any sub-queries you need in your GraphQL setup.